# Python: Recursive counting of walking grid yield error when grid size is large

Tags: python, recursion, grid

I have a problem when dealing with the walking grid problem when the data size is becoming too large.
Project description:
An ant walking from (0,0) to (m,n). Each time, ant travel along path walking north or east by a unit length with equal probability until it reaches (m,n) .Define the deviation D of a path as max(x/m-y/n, y/n-x/m) for all point (x,y) along the path.
MY code:

```
import math
D = []
def all_path(x,y,m,n,d):
    temp = abs(x*1.00/m-y*1.00/n)
    if d < temp:
        d = temp
    if x == m-1 and y==n:
        D.append(d)
    elif x == m and y == n-1:
        D.append(d)
    elif x==m  and y<n-1:
        D.append(d)
    elif x<m-1 and y== n:
        D.append(d)
    else:
        all_path(x+1,y,m,n,d)
        all_path(x,y+1,m,n,d)

all_path(0,0,23,31,0)
D_ave = sum(D)/len(D)
#mean
print(round(D_ave,10))
#standard deviation
print(round(math.sqrt(sum([(d-D_ave)*(d-D_ave) for d in D])/len(D)),10))
count_1= 0
count_2 = 0
for d in D:
    if d >0.2:
        count_1+=1
        if d>0.6:
            count_2+=1
#condition propabality
print(round(count_2*1.00/count_1,10))
```

Problem:
When m and n is small like 11 and 7. It's working fine. But when m and n become a little bit larger like 23 and 31. My computer shows Memory capacity is not sufficient.
I try to run this on my friends computer which has 32g memory. This error is still there. Is the problem coming from my algorithm or something else?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with your algorithm. You recursion depth while calling `all_path` approaches approximately `2 ^ (max(m, n))`. Taking your values m = 23 and n = 31, `2^31` is of the order of `10^9`. Even 32 GB RAM may not be sufficient as the memory required would be `10^9` multiplied by stack size.

Answer (score 1):

It's the nature of the problem and the algorithm you've chosen.  Look at the length of `D` for your smaller cases:

```
 m   n      len(D)
 7, 11       31824
11, 11      705432
12, 12     2704156
13, 13    10400600
14, 14    40116600
```

The time and space complexities are each exponential, with a base of 2 on stack depth and 4 on memory.  With m=n=23, `D` will be on the close order of 10^19 floats.

I suggest that you look into dynamic programming to give you ideas of how to refactor an algorithm.  Also, switch to a breadth-first execution: collate all of the results that got you *to* a given square before you move on to the next.  You can conveniently do this along a row, column, or diagonal (quantity of moves).  That way, you're holding no more than `min(m, n)` parallel threads of computation at any one time, rather than the `2^max(m,n)` you have now.